# Como colocar url da página atual em variável de javascript no blogger

Tags: javascript, html

Eu sei que no blogger o trecho `<a expr:href='data:post.url'>TEXTO</a>` significa que o texto sempre terá o link da página atual aberta, independente de qual página estiver.

Tem como pegar o url do **data:post.url** e colocar em uma variável em javascript?

Por exemplo:

```
<script>
  var url = data:post.url;
</script>
```

Dessa maneira acima não funciona.

Comment: Para fazer isso basta usar `var url = location.href;`

Answer (score 0):

A url via JavaScript se pega a partir do `location`

```
var url = location.href;
```